# For $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $\zeta_k = \exp(2\pi i k/n)$, evaluate $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}|z-\zeta_k|^2$

Tags: complex-numbers, summation, roots-of-unity

> Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $z\in\mathbb{C}$, and $\zeta_k=\exp\left(\frac{2\pi i k}
> {n}\right)$. What is $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}|z-\zeta_k|^2?$

I found this problem in a homework about complex numbers and I couldn't see how to simplify the result. I know that $|z-\zeta_k|^2=|z|^2+|\zeta_k|^2-2\operatorname{Re}(z\bar{\zeta_k})$, and I also know that $|\zeta_k|=1$. Yet somehow I can't figure how to simplify it. Every time I calculate it I get a wrong answer.

Comment: Looks use of $|z|^2=z\bar{z}$.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE.  It will likely help Readers to respond cogently if you put the problem (of evaluating that summation) in a more specific context: What did you try? Where did you encounter this sum?  Why is it important to you?  Thanks for using MathJax!

Comment: $n\,(|z|^2 +1)$

Answer (score 1):

Using what you know already

$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}|z-\zeta_k|^2&=\sum^{n-1}_{j=0}(z-\zeta_k)(\overline{z}-\overline{\zeta_k})=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \big(|z|^2-2\operatorname{Re}(\overline{z}\zeta_k)+|\zeta_k|^2\big)\\
&=n(|z|^2+1) -2\sum^{n-1}_{k=1}\operatorname{Re}(\overline{z}\zeta_k)
\end{align}
$$

Using the properties of the real part function and the fact that $\sum^{n-1}_{k=0}\zeta_k$ is a geometric we get

$$
\sum^{n-1}_{k=1}\operatorname{Re}(\overline{z}\zeta_k)=\operatorname{Re}\left(\overline{z}\sum^{n-1}_{k=0}\zeta_k\right)=\operatorname{Re}\left(\overline{z}\sum^{n-1}_{k=0}e^{\tfrac{i2\pi}{n}k}\right)=\operatorname{Re}\left(\overline{z}\frac{1-e^{i2\pi}}{1-e^{\tfrac{i2\pi}{n}}}\right)=0
$$

Putting things together

$$
\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}|z-\zeta_k|^2 = n(|z|^2+1)
$$

Comment: thanks man that was so helpful